# Pester: Cannot access parent scoped variable

Tags: powershell, scope, pester

I have the following simple test in Pester:

```bsh
# Name.Tests.ps1

$name = "foo"

Describe "Check name" {
  It "should have the correct value" {
    $name | Should -Be "foo"
  }
}
```

So when I navigate to the folder containing the test script and run `Invoke-Pester`, I was expecting the test to pass. Instead, I get the following error:

`[-]Check name.should have the correct value. Expected 'foo', but got $null...`

Any idea why this fails and why `$name` is set to null in the `It` block - shouldn't `$name` still be set to `foo` as it's from the parent scope?

Comment: Try `$global:name`

Comment: What version of Pester are you using?

Comment: @NekoMusume yeah of course `$global:name` and even `$script:name` works but why does it need to be global/script scoped? The examples online don't seem to require that scoping (for eg: https://medium.com/charot/test-arm-templates-using-pester-azure-devops-837b5006c30c)

Comment: @MarkWragg v5.0.2

Comment: You have a typo, `It "should have the correct value` has no ending quotes

Comment: Thanks. Updated the desc.

Comment: This will most likely be because of Pester v5 where tears are pre-discovered which affects how variables are scoped.

Comment: Ok, so probably a bug then? In any case, any suggestions on how the scoping can be fixed but without resorting to global/script scopes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are new rules to follow for Pester v5 and one of them is the following (https://github.com/pester/Pester#discovery--run):

> Put all your code into It, BeforeAll, BeforeEach, AfterAll or
> AfterEach. Put no code directly into Describe, Context or on the top
> of your file, without wrapping it in one of these blocks, unless you
> have a good reason to do so.
> ...
> All misplaced code will run during Discovery, and its results won't be
> available during Run.

So placing the variable assignment in either `BeforeAll` or `BeforeEach` within the `Describe` block should get it working:

```bsh
Describe "Check name" {
  BeforeAll {
    $name = "foo"
  }
  It "should have the correct value" {
    $name | Should -Be "foo"
  }
}
```

Thanks to @Mark Wragg for pointing me to the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i had to do:

```
#mine only happens during a foreach loop
$names = @("foo", "foo2")

Describe "Check name - all errors" {
    foreach($rec in $names)
    {
        It "should have the correct value" {
            $rec | Should -Be "foo"
        }
    }
}

#this is what i had to do to fix it :(
Describe "Check name - fixed" {
    foreach($rec in $names)
    {
        It "should have the correct value" -TestCases @(
            @{
                rec = $rec
            }
        ) {
            $rec | Should -Be "foo"
        }
    }
}
```